# Will PostgreSQL optimize query when the same aggregate usage?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

SQL would not let use aliases (s,d) in other columns, so, my query is:

```
SELECT
   employe,
   sum(salary + bonus) AS s,
   sum(debt) AS d,
   (sum(salary + bonus) - sum(debt)) AS total
      FROM test_table
      GROUP BY employe;
```

This query contain aggregate `sum(salary + bonus)` two times.

Will PostgreSQL optimize it (use result from first aggregate in second aggregate) or do sum again for the second aggregate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't use the aliases is that they don't exist during aggregation, renaming is performed after aggregation. I don't know the answer to your question, I guess the only way to find out for sure is to look at the plan. However, have you considered nesting your query?

```
SELECT employe, s, d, s-d as total
FROM (
    SELECT employe, sum(salary + bonus) AS s
         , sum(debt) AS d,
    FROM test_table
    GROUP BY employe
) as t;
```

another option is to use a CTE:

```
WITH t as ( 
    SELECT employe, sum(salary + bonus) AS s
         , sum(debt) AS d,
    FROM test_table
    GROUP BY employe
)
SELECT employe, s, d, s-d as total
FROM t;
```

Comment: I made several tests with different combinations for aggregate 1,000,000 random series. Where is no difference. Thank you.